# Send Notification To Subscriber Users

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing forexsignals App and i want to send notification to users who subscribe to specsfic currency when inserted in firebase
i Have more then 50 SwitchListTile and should users select ( subscribe to currency)
to get notify.

- im using FCM
  thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Step 1: Setup and configure Firebase core and Firebase messaging.
Step 2: Subscribe to the topic when the boolean of the switch is true and unsubscribe when boolean is false Step3:i want to write the firebase function to send the notification to subscribers

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens, which contains a complete working example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using three simple steps:

**Step 1:** Setup and configure Firebase core and Firebase messaging.
I Assume you have done it already

**Step 2:** Subscribe to the topic when the boolean of the switch is true and unsubscribe when boolean is false
Example:

```
SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text(currency),
      value: _lights,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _lights = value;
          if(value){ 
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(currency);
          }else{
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(currency);
          }
        });
      },
     
    );
```

**Step 3:** On the Server side :

Have a post request of JSON on: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

with json as :

```
{ "notification":  { "body": "Message..", 
                     "title": "Your Title",  
                      "color":"#fabea7", 
                      "image": "image url" 
                    },
  "priority": "high",
  "to":"/topics/currencyyouwant"
 }
```

Comment: i did all steps you said my problem in how to write firebase function that send notification when new curreny is inserted Based on user selection